# How to share projects in github while using proxy in android studio?

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I am behind proxy and trying to share my android project to the github. While trying this, I got the following error:

> Can't finish GitHub sharing process
>            Successfully created project 'SharedPreference' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
>            fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Shiza1aas/SharedPreference.git/': Could not
>   resolve host: github.com

Please help me.

Comment: I think it is out-of-topic. However, you should be able to use VPN such as VPNGate, to bypass the proxy. I should remind you though, on some corporation / country, bypass proxy is considered as illegal activity :)

Comment: I am in my college, so I don't think it matters. In India goverment has banned it. I am from India. But I can easily access the site. But how come I am able to create but unable to push?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind the proxy, try to add the proxy server. 
Run the following command -

`git config --global http.proxy 'PROXY_URL'`

`git config --global https.proxy 'PROXY_URL'`